# Jquery closest with ClipboardJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, clipboard.js

I make a simple coupon clipper with ClipboardJS. My purpose is that when the user clicks on the Coupon button to clip it (copy). The Coupon will display the string Copied, then return to show the original Coupon after a moment.

Unfortunately, if there are two or more coupons on the same page, the returned value will always be the first Coupon. I tried to play around with jQuery closest, but I couldn't figure it out.

Here is my code:

### HTML

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/clipboard.js/2.0.4/clipboard.min.js"></script>
<p>
Clip Coupon <button class="coupon_clipper" data-clipboard-text="10PERCENT">10PERCENT</button> to receive 10% discount for order over 100$
</p>
<p>
Clip Coupon <button class="coupon_clipper" data-clipboard-text="1PERCENT">1PERCENT</button> to receive 1% discount for order over 100$
</p>

<style>
.coupon_clipper {
  border-style: dashed;
}
</style>
```

### Javascript

```js
<script>var cClip = new ClipboardJS('.coupon_clipper');

cClip.on('success', function(e) {
  $(e.trigger).text('Clipped');
  e.clearSelection();
  setTimeout(function() {
    $(e.trigger).text($('.coupon_clipper').closest('.coupon_clipper').attr('data-clipboard-text'));
  }, 250);
});
</script>
```

### JSFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/whitecrown/tckd1820/3/

Comment: You want the closest element to the cliked button: `$(e.target).closest(...)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`e.trigger` return the element you clicked.  So you can use that to get the `attribute` as well as to set text.

Notice

```
let button = e.trigger;
setTimeout(function() {
  $(button).text($(button).attr('data-clipboard-text'));
}, 250);
```

```js
var cClip = new ClipboardJS('.coupon_clipper');

cClip.on('success', function(e) {
  let button = e.trigger;
  e.clearSelection();
  
  $(button).text('Clipped');  
  setTimeout(function() {
    $(button).text($(button).attr('data-clipboard-text'));
  }, 250);
});
```

```css
.coupon_clipper {
  border-style: dashed;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/clipboard.js/2.0.4/clipboard.min.js"></script>
<p>
Clip Coupon <button class="coupon_clipper" data-clipboard-text="10PERCENT">10PERCENT</button> to receive 10% discount for order over 100$
</p>
<p>
Clip Coupon <button class="coupon_clipper" data-clipboard-text="1PERCENT">1PERCENT</button> to receive 1% discount for order over 100$
</p>
```

`$('.coupon_clipper').closest('.coupon_clipper')` this will return always first, you have to think with respective to action you performed on which element. and in your case it will be the same so you can you directly `e.trigger` which returns the button you clicked.

Comment: Oh, you made it so simple, this is actually a much better method to tackle the function. I'm learning something new again in javascript.